# Unity: On scene added/changed event

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

Currently I'm writing a script that automatically writes a file with all the scene names as variables. I would like to catch a certain event (if it exists) so that I could know when any scene was added or changed it's name. Currently I have to manually press a button whenever I add a scene or rename one. But since I'm not going to be the only one on my team using this, I'd like to automate this.

Some kind of update cycle would work too, I could then check if the current build list matches my list and if not, update it.

I've tried [OnHierarchyChange](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnHierarchyChange.html) / [OnProjectChange](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnProjectChange.html), but those only seem to work on certain assets. Any idea to catch this event?

Comment: How about using your CI system to create/update that list? It could refresh it with every checkin to VCS...

Comment: The Update cycle is only called if a window is opened, and I'm not currently showing any windows.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

For Unity 5.3 and below use function OnLevelWasLoaded

http://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html

Unity 5.4 + use event: SceneManager.sceneLoaded

http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html